# Displaying text value as alternate text value

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to display an abbreviation as it's full string. For instance, I have a field with location names in abbreviated format (i.e. the Location abbreviation for Charles Street is "CSST"). The table from which I'm pulling only stores them as abbreviations. I want to use a function that will display "CSST" as "Charles Street" on the report. I played around with if-->then-->ToText formula but it errors out. Is there another function like ToText that will display a value as a string?

Here's what I tried so far:
If {LOCATION}="CSST" then ToText(Charles Street)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking it. Simply removing the "ToText" part and putting (Charles Street) in quotes did the trick.

Code:
if{LOCATION}="CSST" then "Charles Street"